# Anticanonical embedding of the degree $9$ del Pezzo surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

In Wikipedia, on the page on [*del Pezzo surfaces*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Pezzo_surface), it is written that

> The only degree $9$ del Pezzo surface is $\mathbb{P}^2$. Its anticanonical embedding is the degree $3$ Veronese embedding into $\mathbb{P}^9$ using the linear system of cubics.

The only thing that is clear to me here is why there is a degree $3$ embedding in $\mathbb{P}^9$, since we consider monomials of degree $3$ in coordinates $x,y,z$, of which there are a total of ten of them, each corresponding to a coordinate in $\mathbb{P}^9$.

However, how do we see that this is the anticanonical embedding?

Comment: Wikipedia is saying "using the linear system of cubics", not conics.

Comment: @Sasha no wonder I thought conics didn't make sense, I have no idea how I saw it wrongly. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The canonical line bundle of $\mathbb{P}^2$ is $\mathcal{O}(-3)$.

Comment: @Sasha So it follows that the anticanonical bundle is $\mathcal{O}(3)$, and that $|\mathcal{O}(3)|$ is the linear system of cubics, am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: From a toric perspective, you can also say that the toric divisor $D = D_0 + D_1 + D_2$ where $D_i = \{x_i=0\}$ is linearly equivalent to $\mathcal{O}(3)$ in $Cl(\mathbb{P}^2)$ and use the toric polytope associated to this choice of divisor, which has 4+3+2+1=10 lattice points. See my poorly-written blog post here: https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=blog for an example